# How to get data from database javafx

Tags: mysql, database, javafx-2

I have this project and I need to get data (writing) from a database and I am using javaFX. I have a connection class that works (when I run it makes the connection)

```
public class Conexiune extends JPanel {
    public Connection con = null;
    public Statement stmt = null;
    public ResultSet rs = null;

    Vector data = null;
    Vector columns = null;
    JTable table;
    JPanel paneOrar;

    JTable tabel;

    void login() throws SQLException {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/database";
        String login = "root";
        String password = "password";

        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
    }

    Component query() throws SQLException {
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
        ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();

        Vector columns = new Vector(columnCount);

        // store column names
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));

        Vector data = new Vector();
        Vector row;

        // store row data
        while (result.next()) {
            row = new Vector(columnCount);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                row.add(result.getString(i));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabel);

        this.setLayout(null);
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        return this.add(table);
    }

Conexiune() {

        try {

            login();
            System.out.println("bdConnect");

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.err.println(sqle);
        }

    }

}
```

After I run I get the message bdConnect with no errors.

The main problem is that i don't know what to do after, I mean I want to get the text from the database on to something that is not a table. Something like a scrollPane. Lets say i just want a window full of text on multiple lines but not a table. Lets say that you  want to get the contents of a book from your database, you cant put it in a table. Can anyone help me please I'm getting kind of desperate!!!

Comment: You are not using JavaFX. Are you trying to convert some legacy code to JavaFX?

Comment: @Uluk Yes, well i kinda used that code for another application in Java.